# Polygon triangulation into triangle strips for OpenGL ES

Tags: algorithm, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, triangulation, gl-triangle-strip

I am looking for a fast **polygon triangulation algorithm** that can triangulate not very complex 2D concave polygons (without holes) into **triangle strips** ready to be sent to OpenGL ES for drawing using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.

I am aware of some algorithms but I couldn't find one that will fit my needs:

- http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Efficient_Polygon_Triangulation.shtml

  - this algorithm works ok but the problem is it returns simple triangles which you can't draw with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, you need to use `GL_TRIANGLES` which isn't very efficient on a large number of vertices.
- http://code.google.com/p/iphone-glu/

  - it doesn't have any example associated and I couldn't find anyone that has successfully used it on iOS with OpenGL ES 2.0
  - I don't know what it returns and it seems like it also calls the corresponding OpenGL commands which I don't want - I only need the triangles back
  - it leaks memory

The platform I am developing for is: iOS, OpenGL ES 2.0, cocos2d 2.0.

Can anyone help me with such an algorithm? Or any other advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although a list of triangles may seem less efficient than a single triangle strip, it pays when you have more than one such concave polygons to draw (like a real 3d object constructed from them). In this case you can draw the whole multi-polygon object with a single draw call (many tri-lists can be concatenated into one), whereas with a triangle-strip solution you have to draw each polygon indivdually. Nowadays reducing the number of draw calls is often a better idea than crunching objects into some sophisticated primitives, like tri-strips. I guess this also applies for today's ES devices.

Comment: If you have a whole object, it is better to turn it into triangles and feed it to a library which would generate triangle strips, such as nvTriStrip or Stripifier. That can be done offline on PC so one doesn't need to bother porting the library to iOS. The devices also usually support primitive restart, which enables concatenating tristrips to be able to render them using a single command. And then there is glMultiDrawElements() or degenerate strips.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 2D and without holes, this is fairly easy. First, you need to break your polygon to one or more [monotone polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_polygon).

The monotone polygons are pretty simple to turn into tristrips, just sort the values by `y`, find the top-most and bottom-most vertex, and then you have lists of vertices to the right and to the left (because vertices come in some defined, say clockwise, order). Then you start with top-most vertex and add vertices from the left and from the right sides in alternating manner.

This technique will work for any 2D polygons without self-intersecting edges, which includes some cases of polygons with holes (the holes must be correctly wound though).

You can try and play with this code:

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(-.5f, -.5f, 0);

std::vector<Vector2f> my_polygon;

my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(-0.300475f, 0.862924f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.302850f, 1.265013f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.811164f, 1.437337f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(1.001188f, 1.071802f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.692399f, 0.936031f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.934679f, 0.622715f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.644893f, 0.408616f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.592637f, 0.753264f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.269596f, 0.278068f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.996437f, -0.092689f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.735154f, -0.338120f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.112827f, 0.079634f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(-0.167458f, 0.330287f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.008314f, 0.664491f));
my_polygon.push_back(Vector2f(0.393112f, 1.040470f));
// from wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Polygon-to-monotone.png)

glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glLineWidth(6);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
for(size_t i = 0, n = my_polygon.size(); i < n; ++ i)
    glVertex2f(my_polygon[i].x, my_polygon[i].y);
glEnd();
glPointSize(6);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for(size_t i = 0, n = my_polygon.size(); i < n; ++ i)
    glVertex2f(my_polygon[i].x, my_polygon[i].y);
glEnd();
// draw the original polygon

std::vector<int> working_set;
for(size_t i = 0, n = my_polygon.size(); i < n; ++ i)
    working_set.push_back(i);
_ASSERTE(working_set.size() == my_polygon.size());
// add vertex indices to the list (could be done using iota)

std::list<std::vector<int> > monotone_poly_list;
// list of monotone polygons (the output)

glPointSize(14);
glLineWidth(4);
// prepare to draw split points and slice lines

for(;;) {
    std::vector<int> sorted_vertex_list;
    {
        for(size_t i = 0, n = working_set.size(); i < n; ++ i)
            sorted_vertex_list.push_back(i);
        _ASSERTE(working_set.size() == working_set.size());
        // add vertex indices to the list (could be done using iota)

        for(;;) {
            bool b_change = false;

            for(size_t i = 1, n = sorted_vertex_list.size(); i < n; ++ i) {
                int a = sorted_vertex_list[i - 1];
                int b = sorted_vertex_list[i];
                if(my_polygon[working_set[a]].y < my_polygon[working_set[b]].y) {
                    std::swap(sorted_vertex_list[i - 1], sorted_vertex_list[i]);
                    b_change = true;
                }
            }

            if(!b_change)
                break;
        }
        // sort vertex indices by the y coordinate
        // (note this is using bubblesort to maintain portability
        // but it should be done using a better sorting method)
    }
    // build sorted vertex list

    bool b_change = false;
    for(size_t i = 0, n = sorted_vertex_list.size(), m = working_set.size(); i < n; ++ i) {
        int n_ith = sorted_vertex_list[i];
        Vector2f ith = my_polygon[working_set[n_ith]];
        Vector2f prev = my_polygon[working_set[(n_ith + m - 1) % m]];
        Vector2f next = my_polygon[working_set[(n_ith + 1) % m]];
        // get point in the list, and get it's neighbours
        // (neighbours are not in sorted list ordering
        // but in the original polygon order)

        float sidePrev = sign(ith.y - prev.y);
        float sideNext = sign(ith.y - next.y);
        // calculate which side they lie on
        // (sign function gives -1 for negative and 1 for positive argument)

        if(sidePrev * sideNext >= 0) { // if they are both on the same side
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2f(ith.x, ith.y);
            glEnd();
            // marks points whose neighbours are both on the same side (split points)

            int n_next = -1;
            if(sidePrev + sideNext > 0) {
                if(i > 0)
                    n_next = sorted_vertex_list[i - 1];
                // get the next vertex above it
            } else {
                if(i + 1 < n)
                    n_next = sorted_vertex_list[i + 1];
                // get the next vertex below it
            }
            // this is kind of simplistic, one needs to check if
            // a line between n_ith and n_next doesn't exit the polygon
            // (but that doesn't happen in the example)

            if(n_next != -1) {
                glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
                glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2f(my_polygon[working_set[n_next]].x, my_polygon[working_set[n_next]].y);
                glEnd();
                glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex2f(ith.x, ith.y);
                glVertex2f(my_polygon[working_set[n_next]].x, my_polygon[working_set[n_next]].y);
                glEnd();

                std::vector<int> poly, remove_list;

                int n_last = n_ith;
                if(n_last > n_next)
                    std::swap(n_last, n_next);
                int idx = n_next;
                poly.push_back(working_set[idx]); // add n_next
                for(idx = (idx + 1) % m; idx != n_last; idx = (idx + 1) % m) {
                    poly.push_back(working_set[idx]);
                    // add it to the polygon

                    remove_list.push_back(idx);
                    // mark this vertex to be erased from the working set
                }
                poly.push_back(working_set[idx]); // add n_ith
                // build a new monotone polygon by cutting the original one

                std::sort(remove_list.begin(), remove_list.end());
                for(size_t i = remove_list.size(); i > 0; -- i) {
                    int n_which = remove_list[i - 1];
                    working_set.erase(working_set.begin() + n_which);
                }
                // sort indices of vertices to be removed and remove them
                // from the working set (have to do it in reverse order)

                monotone_poly_list.push_back(poly);
                // add it to the list

                b_change = true;

                break;
                // the polygon was sliced, restart the algorithm, regenerate sorted list and slice again
            }
        }
    }

    if(!b_change)
        break;
    // no moves
}

if(!working_set.empty())
    monotone_poly_list.push_back(working_set);
// use the remaining vertices (which the algorithm was unable to slice) as the last polygon

std::list<std::vector<int> >::const_iterator p_mono_poly = monotone_poly_list.begin();
for(; p_mono_poly != monotone_poly_list.end(); ++ p_mono_poly) {
    const std::vector<int> &r_mono_poly = *p_mono_poly;

    glLineWidth(2);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(size_t i = 0, n = r_mono_poly.size(); i < n; ++ i)
        glVertex2f(my_polygon[r_mono_poly[i]].x, my_polygon[r_mono_poly[i]].y);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(2);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(size_t i = 0, n = r_mono_poly.size(); i < n; ++ i)
        glVertex2f(my_polygon[r_mono_poly[i]].x, my_polygon[r_mono_poly[i]].y);
    glEnd();
    // draw the sliced part of the polygon

    int n_top = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0, n = r_mono_poly.size(); i < n; ++ i) {
        if(my_polygon[r_mono_poly[i]].y < my_polygon[r_mono_poly[n_top]].y)
            n_top = i;
    }
    // find the top-most point

    glLineWidth(1);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex2f(my_polygon[r_mono_poly[n_top]].x, my_polygon[r_mono_poly[n_top]].y);
    for(size_t i = 1, n = r_mono_poly.size(); i <= n; ++ i) {
        int n_which = (n_top + ((i & 1)? n - i / 2 : i / 2)) % n;
        glVertex2f(my_polygon[r_mono_poly[n_which]].x, my_polygon[r_mono_poly[n_which]].y);
    }
    glEnd();
    // draw as if triangle strip
}
```

This code is not optimal, but it should be easy to understand. At the beginnig, a concave polygon is created. Then a "working set" of vertices is created. On that working set, a permutation is calculated which sorts the vertices by their `y` coordinate. That permutation is then looped through, looking for split points. Once a split point is found, a new monotone polygon is created. Then, the vertices used in the new polygon are removed from the working set and the whole process repeats. Finally, the working set contains the last polygon which could not be split. At the end, the monotone polygons are rendered, along with triangle strip ordering. It is a little bit messy, but I'm sure you will figure it out (this is C++ code, just put it inside a GLUT window and see what it does).

Hope this helps ...

Comment: @rakeshNS That nickname actually goes way back. In high school, I used to make all kinds of homeworks/assignments for the rest of the class, and if they started worrying that I will not make their in time and they would lose credits, I always reassured them "don't worry, I'm no swine" ... and it kind of stuck.

Comment: If the left monotone polyline has less vertices than the right one, should additional vertices be added artificially to the left polyline to let the algorithm keep going?..

Comment: @BrianHaak There is usually little sense in adding extra duplicate vertices as they won't be rendered anyway. I think in the example, the left / right half is not balanced either.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract tesselation algorithm from OpenGL Sample Implementation, like described in this post http://choruscode.blogspot.de/2013/03/extracting-tesselation-from-opengl.html , it also has an example.