# GL_TRIANGLES vs GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP

Tags: opengl, mapping, textures

Lets say i have a concave polygon and want to map a texture on it. Can I use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP on it? I guess no because three consecutive points can form a triangle "outside" the actual polygon. Until now, I was triangulating the polygon manually and call glDrawArray with GL_TRIANGLES parameter which works fine. So my question is: Is the triangulation/decomposition unavoidable for a concave polygon? (In the first case, triangulate and use GL_TRIANGLES, 2nd case decomposition in convex sub_polygons, not necessary triangles, and use GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980379/polygon-triangulation-into-triangle-strips-for-opengl-es

Comment: yep it actually answers my question, thx