# OpenGL -- GL_LINE_LOOP --

Tags: c, opengl, colors, geometry

I am using GL_LINE_LOOP to draw a circle in C and openGL! Is it possible for me to fill the circle with colors?

If needed, this is the code I'm using:

```
        const int circle_points=100;
        const float cx=50+i, cy=50+x, r=50;
        const float pi = 3.14159f;
        int i = 50;

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

        for(i=0;i<circle_points;i++)
        {
            const float theta=(2*pi*i)/circle_points;
            glVertex2f(cx+r*cos(theta),cy+r*sin(theta));
        }
        glEnd();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A line loop is just an outline.

To fill the middle as well, you want to use `GL_POLYGON`.

Comment: Just be aware that `GL_POLYGON` only works for *convex* arrangements of points. A circle is convex, but not all shapes have this property. This of course assumes that your implementation still supports `GL_POLYGON`, as it is deprecated it is probably best to avoid it and learn how to build your circle out of something like a triangle fan.

Answer (score 10):

### Lookup polygon triangulation!

I hope something here is somehow useful to someone, even though this question was asked in February. There are many answers, even though a lot of people would give none. I could witter forever, but I'll try to finish before then.

Some would even say, "You never would," or, "That's not appropriate for OpenGL," I'd like to say more than them about *why*. Converting polygons into the triangles that OpenGL likes so much is outside of OpenGL's job-spec, and is probably better done on the processor side anyway. Calculate that stage in advance, as few times as possible, rather than repeatedly sending such a chunky problem on every draw call.

Perhaps the original questioner drifted away from OpenGL since February, or perhaps they've become an expert. Perhaps I'll re-inspire them to look at it again, to hack away at some original 'imposters'. Or maybe they'll say it's not the tool for them after all, but that would be disappointing. Whatever graphics code you're writing, you know that OpenGL can speed it up!

**Triangles for convex polygons are easy**

Do you just want a circle? Make a triangle fan with the shared point at the circle's origin. GL_POLYGON was, for better or worse, deprecated then killed off entirely; it will not work with current or future implementations of OpenGL.

**Triangles for concave polygons are hard**

You'll want more general polygons later? Well, there are some tricks you could play with, for all manner of convex polygons, but concave ones will soon get difficult. It would be easy to start five different solutions without finishing a single one. Then it would be difficult, on finishing one, to make it quick, and nearly impossible to be sure that it's the quickest.

To achieve it in a future-proofed way you really want to stick with triangles -- so "polygon triangulation" is the subject you want to search for. OpenGL will always be great for drawing triangles. Triangle strips are popular because they reuse many vertices, and a whole mesh can be covered with only triangle strips, (perhaps including the odd lone triangle or pair of triangles). Drawing with only one primitive usually means the entire mesh can be rendered with a single draw call, which *could* improve performance. (Number of draw calls is one performance consideration, but not always the most important.)

Polygon triangulation gets more complex when you allow convex polygons or polygons with holes. (Finding algorithms for triangulating a general polygon, robustly yet quickly, is actually an area of ongoing research. Nonetheless, you can find some pretty good solutions out there that are probably fit for purpose.)

**But is this what you want?**

Is a filled polygon crucial to your final goals in OpenGL? Or did you simply choose what felt like it would be a simple early lesson?

Frustratingly, although drawing a filled polygon seems like a simple thing to do -- and indeed is one of the simplest things to do in many languages -- the solution in OpenGL is likely to be quite complicated. Of course, it can be done if we're clever enough -- but that could be a lot of effort, without being the best route to take towards your later goals.

Even in languages that implement filled polygons in a way that is simple to program with, you don't always know how much strain it puts on the CPU or GPU. If you send a sequence of vertices, to be linked and filled, once every animation frame, will it be slow? If a polygon doesn't change shape, perhaps you should do the difficult part of the calculation just once? You will be doing just that, if you triangulate a polygon once using the CPU, then repeatedly send those triangles to OpenGL for rendering.

OpenGL is very, very good at doing certain things, very quickly, taking advantage of hardware acceleration. It is worth appreciating what it is and is not optimal for, to decide your best route towards your final goals with OpenGL.

If you're looking for a simple early lesson, rotating brightly coloured tetrahedrons is ideal, and happens early in most tutorials.

If on the other hand, you're planning a project that you currently envision using filled polygons a great deal -- say, a stylized cartoon rendering engine for instance -- I still advise going to the tutorials, and even more so! Find a good one; stick with it to the end; you can then think better about OpenGL functions that are and aren't available to you. What can you take advantage of? What do you need or want to redo in software? And is it worth writing your own code for apparently simple things -- like drawing filled polygons -- that are 'missing from' (or at least inappropriate to) OpenGL?

Is there a higher level graphics library, free to use -- perhaps relying on OpenGL for rasterisation -- that can already do want you want? If so, how much freedom does it give you, to mess with the nuts and bolts of OpenGL itself?

OpenGL is very good at drawing points, lines, and triangles, and hardware accelerating certain common operations such as clipping, face culling, perspective divides, perspective texture accesses (very useful for lighting) and so on. It offers you a chance to write special programs called shaders, which operate at various stages of the rendering pipeline, maximising your chance to insert your own unique cleverness while still taking advantage of hardware acceleration.

A good tutorial is one that explains the rendering pipeline and puts you in a much better position to assess what the tool of OpenGL is best used for.
Here is one such tutorial that I found recently: [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming
by Jason L. McKesson](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/). It doesn't appear to be complete, but if you get far enough for that to annoy you, you'll be well placed to search for the rest.

**Using imposters to fill polygons**

Everything in computer graphics is an imposter, but the term often has a specialised meaning. Imposters display very different geometry from what they actually have -- only more so than usual! Of course, a 3D world is very different from the pixels representing it, but with imposters, the deception goes deeper than usual.

For instance, a rectangle that OpenGL actually constructs out of two triangles can appear to be a sphere if, in its fragment shader, you write a customised depth value to the depth coordinate, calculate your own normals for lighting and so on, and discard those fragments of the square that would fall outside the outline of the sphere. (Calculating the depth on those fragments would involve a square root of a negative number, which can be used to discard the fragment.) Imposters like that are sometimes called flat cards or billboards.

*(The tutorial above includes a chapter on imposters, and examples doing just what I've described here. In fact, the rectangle itself is constructed only part way through the pipeline, from a single point. I warn that the scaling of their rectangle, to account for the way that perspective distorts a sphere into an ellipse in a wide FOV, is a non-robust* fudge *. The correct and robust answer is tricky to work out, using mathematics that would be slightly beyond the scope of the book. I'd say it is beyond the author's algebra skills to work it out but I could be wrong; he'd certainly understand a worked example. However, when you have the correct solution, it is computationally inexpensive; it involves only linear operations plus two square roots, to find the four limits of a horizontally- or vertically-translated sphere. To generalise that technique for other displacements requires one more square root, for a vector normalisation to find the correct rotation, and one application of that rotation matrix when you render the rectangle.)*

So just to suggest an original solution that others aren't likely to provide, you could use an inequality (like x * x + y * y <= 1 for a circle or x * x - y * y <= 1 for a hyperbola) or a system of inequalities (like three straight line forms to bound a triangle) to decide how to discard a fragment. Note that if inequalities have more than linear order, they can encode perfect curves, and render them just as smoothly as your pixelated screen will allow -- with no limitation on the 'geometric detail' of the curve. You can also combine straight and curved edges in a single polygon, in this way.

For instance, a fragment shader (which would be written in GLSL) for a semi-circle might have something like this:

```
if (y < 0) discard;
float rSq = x * x + y * y;
if (1 < rSq) discard;
// We're inside the semi-circle; put further shader computations here
```

However, the polygons that are easy to draw, in this way, are very different from the ones that you're used to being easy. Converting a sequence of connected nodes into inequalities means yet more code to write, and deciding on the Boolean logic, to deal with combining those inequalities, could then get quite complex -- especially for concave polygons. Performing inequalities in a sensible order, so that some can be culled based on the results of others, is another ill-posed headache of a problem, if it needs to be general, even though it is easy to hard-code an optimal solution for a single case like a square.

I suggest using imposters mainly for its contrast with the triangulation method. Something like either one could be a route to pursue, depending on what you're hoping to achieve in the end, and the nature of your polygons.

Have fun...

---

P.S. have a related topic... [Polygon triangulation into triangle strips for OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980379/polygon-triangulation-into-triangle-strips-for-opengl-es)

As long as the link lasts, it's a more detailed explanation of 'polygon triangulation' than mine. Those are the two words to search for if the link ever dies.